# How to sample geometry points such that overall view remains same

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, folium

I have a postgres table containing 1 million data points(lon, lat) which I am plotting using folium. But it takes a lot of time to load as the data size is large. The points are plotted with the intention to see like where traces are present.
I don't want to sample randomly, because that might result in data loss where there is sparse data.
How can the points be sampled such that from a zoomed out level(lets say 10/11), the overall view would look exactly same but with less data points.

Comment: I would use random sampling and trust in the law of big numbers.

Comment: There are places where data is sparse, the view would become distorted in case of random sampling

Comment: Perhaps you can use human intelligence by adding an attribute to your points that makes them eligible for a zoomed out view, and by setting that attribute manually for strategic points.

Comment: 1 million data points is less than a screen capture of a PC screen. Why it takes long to load? Maybe you are formating it wrongly. Is text?

Comment: create a grid, then return the 1st/random point from each grid cell, or the count of points per cell